# Can't step Into and debug the serviced component source code

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, com+, servicedcomponent

I have developed a COM+ Component in C# be inheriting ServicedComponent.
Here is how it looks like:

```
    [Transaction(TransactionOption.Required)]
    [ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.AutoDual)]
    [EventTrackingEnabledAttribute(true)]
    [JustInTimeActivation]
    [ObjectPooling(Enabled = true, MinPoolSize = 10, MaxPoolSize = 30, CreationTimeout = 15000)]
    [Synchronization]

    class MyComponent: System.EnterpriseServices.ServicedComponent
    {
        [AutoComplete(true)]
        public string getHello()
        {//2nd breakpoint
            ContextUtil.SetComplete();
            return "HelloWorld";
        }
    }
```

I have another test project from which I call this component.

```
class Program
{
static void Main(string[] args)
{
MyComponent myComp = new MyComponent();
myComp.getHello();//1st Breakpoint
}
}
```

I am not able to reach 2nd Breakpoint. This was working before I switched to VS 2012. Strange thing is after switching to 2012 its no longer working in VS 2010 too.

I've already tried,

- Attach to process
- Unchecked "Enable Just My Code" in debug settings

Can someone please give direction from here?

**UPDATE 1**

From the links given by Mike, I tried symchk for my DLL in the same folder where DLL and PDB files were there. It fails with error saying PDB mismatched or not found. I don't know how to resolve this error.

Answer (score 5):

You may be missing the .pdb file in your project.

Check this microsoft link out for an explanation: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yd4f8bd1(vs.71).aspx

Comment: When I build the project, I see the .pdb file in my debug folder. Is there a way I can check if that's linked properly while debugging?

Comment: This is probably unlikely, but another thing that can cause this is having an outdated .dll in your GAC. I am not sure if you can check to see what the linker is using. My experience has been missing pdb. Here is a more robust article on the topic: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee416588(v=vs.85).aspx - Sorry, wish I could be of more help

Comment: Thanks for the links, I'll go through them and see if that helps!

Comment: symchk failed with mismatch or no files found error. :(